# Enlarge 3 Circles about the same factor to find the Intersect

Tags: linear-algebra, circles

I currently have 3 circles that not intersect at all.

Like this:
[image]

Now i would like enlarge the circles about the same factor to find the intersection of this three circles.

I have tried following some other intersecting posts and maths but haven't managed to fully understand the principles behind them.

Hope somebody can give me a hint or explain me if it's working.

thanks
[image: expand circles]

Comment: What dou you mean by 'enlarge about the same factor'? Do you want to multiply all three radii by the same number $k>1$: $$\begin{align}r_1 \to k\,r_1 \\ r_2 \to k\,r_2 \\ r_3 \to k\,r_3\end{align}$$ or increment each radius by the same amount $d > 0$:  $$\begin{align}r_1 \to r_1 + d \\ r_2 \to r_2 + d \\ r_3 \to r_3 + d\end{align}$$

Comment: Ahh sorry i forgot to mention. For a factor < 1 i multiply the radius with (for example) 0.5 and increment the radius with this result. radii + (radii * factor) and if it > 1 i only multiply. it

Comment: Okay that's a multiplication.  Technically your factor method is a little redundant: for any factor $0 < f < 1$ you get the same result as you would had you used $f+1$ instead.

Comment: Something else is funny here, though: the three circles in the diagram are being scaled by obviously very different factors, especially circle 2, the green one.  What's going on here?

Comment: Yes the picturces were not the best. i changed the coordinate system and uploaded the pictures again.

Comment: Essentailly, you want to find a point $P$ whose ratios of distances to the 3 centers $C_1, C_2, C_3$ are proportional to the radii $r_1, r_2, r_3$. i.e $$PC_1 : PC_2 : PC_3 = r_1 : r_2 : r_3$$ The locus for $PC_i/PC_j = r_i/r_j$ is a circle (or a perpendicular bisector when $r_i = r_j$). The point $P$ is the intersection of 3 circles.

Comment: Note that you only need two of the locus circles; the third will naturally intersect in the same place.

Comment: Sorry maybe it's easy but i don't understand you comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Our first task is to, given two of the circles, find the places where they will intersect as we grow them.  This will be a circle (which I'll call a locus circle), though I won't prove it here.

WLOG we can assume that the circles are 1 unit apart, and that the larger of the two has radius $a$ and the smaller has radius $b$.  There are then two scale factors that are easy to calculate and give known locations:
$$aj + bj = 1$$
which describes a point between the two circle centers, and 
$$ak = bk + 1$$
which describes a point somewhere past the center of the smaller circle.  Solving for their distances from the center of circle $A$, we get
$$aj=\frac{a}{a+b}$$
$$ak=\frac{a}{a-b}$$
Halfway between these is the center of the locus circle.
$$t=a\frac{k+j}{2}=\frac{a^2}{a^2-b^2}$$
And half the distance between them is the radius of the locus circle.
$$r=a\frac{k-j}{2}=\frac{ab}{a^2-b^2}$$
Now that we know what the circle looks like, let's put it back into the real space of our circles.

The center of the circle is based on the centers of the original circles, which we'll call $A$ and $B$.

$$P = (1-t)A+tB$$

The radius is a distance, and we need the original distance between $A$ and $B$: $|A-B|$.

$$p = r|A-B|$$

This process so far -- using the formulas for $t$, $r$, $P$, and $p$ -- gets you one of two locus circles.  Now we need to get another, which works the same way; just use $A$ and $C$ instead, to create $Q$ and $q$.

Once we have the two locus circles, we can find their intersections (of which, hopefully, there are two).  We'll call those $X$ and $Y$.

Your growth factor then is $$F = \frac{|X-A|}{a}$$
Or maybe it's $Y-A$ instead; either of the two is a location where all three circles can meet.

Comment: Hey Dan, first off all thanks for your explanation and sorry for the long delay. I try it with some values but i stuke at the point where you calculate $$p$$ and $$P$$.
Or may i misunderstood something before. 
Here are my solutions for 2 two circles.

Distance is 1

$$ a = 0.3333 $$
$$ b = 0.2500 $$
$$ aj = 0.571428571428572 $$
$$ ak = 4.000000000000001 $$
$$ t = 2.285714285714287 $$
$$ r = 1.714285714285715 $$
$$ P = (1-t)A+tB  = (1 - 2.285714285714287)0 + 2.285714285714287 * 1 = 2.285714285714287$$
$$ p = r|A-B| = 1.714285714285715 * |0-1| $$

is that correct?
Thanks for your help

Comment: That's correct.  You can also (and for the purposes of the problem, should) use *locations* for $A$ and $B$; standard vector arithmetic applies.  P and p don't look that different from t and r in this case because you've chosen the locations of A and B to be the same in the real space of the problem (where P and p actually live) as they are in the simplified space we used to calculate t and r.

Comment: Oh, and you don't need to actually calculate $aj$ and $ak$; they're not used later.

Comment: Hey Dan, again sorry for the long delay.
Ok now i try it with my example from my Question. [This one](https://www.dropbox.com/s/z22gvx1urhyp42c/Starting_point.png?dl=0). With this distance i get different results for $$ t $$ and $$ r$$.
$$Circle A: (4;0) $$
$$Radius: 5 $$
$$Circle B: (0;10)$$
$$Radius: 1.5 $$
$$Distance: 10.770329614269007 $$
$$ j: 1.656973786810617 $$
$$ k: 3.077237032648288 $$$$ t =  a\frac{k+j}{2} = 1.098901098901099 $$
$$ t =  \frac{a^2}{a^2-b^2} = 11.835527048647261 $$
$$ r =  a\frac{k-j}{2} = 0.329670329670330 $$ 
$$ r =  \frac{ab}{a^2-b^2} = 3.550658114594179 $$

Comment: SOmething is going on in your calculations using (a^2-b^2).  Specifically somehow you're multiplying in a factor of $Distance$ somewhere.  For the record, you do not need to adjust the radii when applying these formula; since you're doing only multiplicative scaling, the original radii work fine.

Comment: huuu your right.This was a mistake when writing. $$ a\frac{k+j}{2} = 11.835527048647261$$ and (a^2-b^2) = 1.098901098901099.And also the last 2 results of $$r$$ should inverted. And what do you mean with ajust the radii?

Comment: Usually when we do this sort of scaling etc we need to scale not only the points, but the radii of circles.  In this case however we don't; the result is the same whether we use 3 and 5, 30 and 50, or 1 and 5/3.  THis is because the radii are really *ratios*, which don't change. -- oh, if you switched them around, then you probably miscalculated $j$ and $k$; you shouldn't use those values though, because I didn't give you a direct formula for those.  Use the ones that are just $a$ and $b$

Comment: Ok now i only work with a and b and it worked. Thanks for your help and for the fast responding.

Comment: And for anyone who have interest for the result. With my Values and radii, the growth factor is 1.6678